# If there's a pandas row with two distinct value, do this

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe (df) that looks like this

```
   Phase  Sig  EJO
0      1    -1    2
1      1     0    2
2      1     1    2
3      2    -1    7
4      2     1    1
```

I want to figure how to write a statement such that if there is any row with a 1 for Phase and 0 for Sig to multiple that row's EJO by 2

This is my desired output

```
   Phase  Sig  EJO
0      1    -1    2
1      1     0    4
2      1     1    2
3      2    -1    7
4      2     1    1
```

I will be doing this on a much larger scale

Comment: That would work, but if the OP wanted to multiply by, e.g., 3 instead of 2, it wouldn't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where`:

```
df['EJO'] = df['EJO'] * np.where(df['Phase'].eq(1) & df['Sig'].eq(0), 2, 1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Phase  Sig  EJO
0      1   -1    2
1      1    0    4
2      1    1    2
3      2   -1    7
4      2    1    1
```